# Why is my default constructor for array not getting called here?

Tags: c#, default-constructor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              A[] a = new A[10];
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        static int x;

        public A()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("default A");
        }

        public A(int x1)
        {
            x = x1;
            System.Console.WriteLine("parametered A");

        }
        public void Fun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("asd");
        }
    }    
}
```

Why is my default constructor not getting called here? What Am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A[] a = new A[10];` will only create an array that can hold 10 instances of `A`, but the references are initialized to `null`. You will have to create those instances first, e.g. `a[0] = new A();`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays by default are initialized with null values. They are containers of the type at hand, not actual objects of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring an array that *can* hold 10 instances of A, but you have not allocated any A instances yet. You would have to `new A()` and put them in  the array.

Answer (score 0):

need to initialize as well

```
 A[] a = new A[2] { new A(), new A() };
 A[] a = new A[] { new A(), new A() };
 A[] a = { new A(), new A() };
```